# Evaluating $\int f_1 f_2$ for measurable functions $f_1,f_2\ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f_1,f_2$ are nonnegative measurable functions defined on a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, and $f_3(y)=\int_{\lbrace x\in A: f_2> y\rbrace } f_1(x)dx$. Then $$\int_A f_1(x)f_2(x)dx=\int _0 ^\infty f_3(x)dx$$

I tried using Tonelli's Theorem. $\int_0 ^\infty f_3(y)dy=\int_0 ^\infty(\int _{\lbrace x\in A: f_2> y\rbrace }f(x)dx)dy=\int _0 ^\infty f(x)dx\cdot \int_{\lbrace x\in A: f_2> y\rbrace }dy$ but I don't see how $\int_{\lbrace x\in A: f_2> y\rbrace }dy$ turns into $f_2$ and becomes part of the other integrand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that $f_1 \ge 0$ you get
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty f_3(x)dx &=
\int_0^\infty \int_{t\in A, f_2(t) > x} f_1(t) dt dx \\&=
\int_0^\infty \int_{t\in A} f_1(t) 1_{f_2(t) > x} dt dx \\&=
\int_{t\in A} f_1(t)  \int_0^\infty  1_{f_2(t) > x}  dx dt 
\end{align}

Here the inner integral evaluates, provided that $f_2 \ge 0$, to
$$
\int_0^\infty  1_{f_2(t) > x}  dx = f_2(t)
$$